# Vagrant provision — dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin

Tags: meteor, dpkg, vagrant-provision

I am writing a provision script for Vagrant to install all the packages necessary for deploying an app developed with Meteor 1.6. So far, the script is working well, but at three points during its execution, I get the following output in red in the terminal window:

```
==> default: dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
```

This happens once each while the following packages are installing:
* MongoDB
* nginx
* Phusion Passenger

I haven't yet seen any adverse side-effects

Is this a warning or an error?
What is dpkg-preconfigure trying to do?
What do I need to do to handle it elegantly?

Comment: This [question and answer](https://serverfault.com/a/670688/241984) should help.

Answer (score 11):

Add this line to your provisioning script to prevent debconf from
trying to open stdin:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04

(Thanks to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/500764/dpkg-reconfigure-unable-to-re-open-stdin-no-file-or-directory?newreg=ab3bcf217d7e4a42bbbd82c3ce852392))

Comment: It seems not to work for `dpkg-preconfigure` though.

Comment: Works for `dpkg-preconfigure` right now on 22.04 LTS (jammy64).